# JQuery Datepicker Set End Year Greater Than Start Year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've been searching this through out the internet but most of it provide solution for full date while in my case, I only have the **YEAR**.

My situation is I have two datepicker that only showing the YEAR, no month and day. I'm struggling to make the End Year dropdown list to be equal to or greater than the Start Year.

Any hint will be much appreciated

Below are my code:

```
    // from year datepicker
        $('body').on('focus',"#sectionD_1_year", function(){
            $(this).datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy',
                yearRange: '-27:+0',
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
                }
            });
        });
        // to year datepicker
        $('body').on('focus',"#sectionD_1_year_to", function(){
            $(this).datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy',
                yearRange: '-27:+0',
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: any hint from anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this post. I´m not an expert but what if you use the date-range example provided here? 
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

And add your parameters;

changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
dateFormat: 'yy',
yearRange: '-27:+0',